# Difference between flat of a vector and dual of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

The [flat of a vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) $X\in T_p(M)$ is defined as a dual vector $X^\flat\in T_p^*(M)$ given by the following map on vectors: $$ Y\stackrel{X^\flat}{\mapsto} g(X,Y) $$

The dual of a basis vector $e_j$ is just map $$e_k \stackrel{e^j}{\mapsto} \delta_{kj} $$

What is the relationship between these two notions?

In particular, if on a Lorentzian manifold I pick an orthonormal basis such that $g(e_1,e_1)=-1,\,\dots,\,g(e_j,e_j)=-1,\,g(e_{j+1},e_{j+1})=+1,\,\dots,\,g(e_n,e_n)=+1$ and all other products are zero, then the flat of such a basis vector and its dual are not the same. Is this true? What is the general relationship between flat and dual?

In particular, when defining a tetrad, which one do you use when you need "upper indexed" objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dual $V^{\ast}$ of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ is the vector space comprising the linear functions from $V$ to the base field. There is no preferred, natural way to associate an element of the dual $V^{\ast}$ to an element of $V$. However, given an ordered basis $\{e_{1}, \dots, e_{n}\}$ of $V$ there is a unique ordered basis $\{e^{1}, \dots, e^{n}\}$ of $V^{\ast}$ such that $e^{i}(e_{j})$ equals $1$ or $0$ as $i$ and $j$ coincide or not. Here $e^{i}$ is regarded as a linear function on $V$ and $e^{i}(e_{j})$ means the result of evaluating this function at $e_{j}$.

A metric $g$ on $V$ is simply a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form on $V$. For $X \in V$, the (evidently linear) map $Y \to g(X, Y)$ defines a linear function on $V$, so an element of $V^{\ast}$, which is $X^{\flat}$. That is, $X^{\flat}(Y) = g(X, Y)$. Thus $g$ determines a linear map $\flat: V \to V^{\ast}$. By definition that $g$ be nondegenerate means that this map $\flat$ is an isomorphism.

Suppose $g$ is positive definite. That an ordered basis $\{e_{1}, \dots, e_{n}\}$ be orthonormal is equivalent to $\{e_{1}^{\flat}, \dots, e_{n}^{\flat}\}$ being the dual ordered basis of $V^{\ast}$. However, if $g$ has mixed signature as in the example given in the question, then the dual basis is $$\{e^{1} = -e_{1}^{\flat}, \dots, e^{j} = -e_{j}^{\flat}, e^{j+1} = e_{j+1}^{\flat}, \dots, e^{n} = e_{n}^{\flat}\}.$$ Usually one chooses the dual basis as described above, so that when paired with the basis of $V$ the result is given by the Kronecker symbol. This means that the dual basis does not consist simply of the "flats" of the given basis, rather it consists of these "flats" modified by signs, as above. One can do whatever one finds congenial, but the convention of choosing the dual basis to yield the Kronecker symbol tends to minimize explicit appearance of signs. A tetrad means a basis of a four-dimensional vector space. The dual tetrad just means the dual basis (determined by the Kronecker symbol). In mixed signature a tetrad and its dual are not identified by the flat operation. Rather, they are identified up to signs.